# my copy file function isn't working as expected

Tags: c, gcc

Here is a simple program that should copy the content of one
file named `copyme` into a file `here`. I have created `copyme` with a little text in it by the following commands:

```
touch copyme.txt
open copyme.txt
```

Then I typed in text, and saved the file with
`touch copyme.txt` command.

Then I compiled a program:

```
// Program to copy one file ot another

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char in_name[64], out_name[64];
    FILE *in, *out;
    int c;

    // get file names from user

    printf("Enter name of file to be copied: ");
    scanf("%63s", in_name);

    printf("Entere name of output file: ");
    scanf("%63s", out_name);

    // open input and output files

    if ( (in = fopen(in_name, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", in_name);
        return 1;
    }

    if ( (out = fopen(out_name, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s for writing.\n", out_name);
        return 2;
    }

    while ((c = getc(in)) != EOF)
        putc(c, out);

    // Close open files

    fclose (in);
    fclose (out);

    printf("File has been copied\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And ran it in terminal. 
Here is the output:

```
Enter name of file to be copied: copyme
Entere name of output file: here
Can't open copyme for reading.
```

The compiler doesn't recognize `copyme` file, although it is 
physically exists in the folder (I see it, I open it, I read 
it). 
I would be grateful for help. I am new to this things. 
Thank you!

Comment: It looks as if you don't have the rights to access this file

Comment: look at the `man` page for fopen to get the error

Comment: you created a file called copyme.txt then typed copyme as the file name!

Comment: What does this have to do with `redirect`?

Comment: What is this "open" command you refer to? Why would 'touching' it cause content you typed to be saved? What does that or redirect or '>' having anything to do with code you provided which is basically attempting to copy a file you are reading into a an output file?

Comment: @pm100 oh! thank you! exactly. I blindly followed the book's text - they don't have any extension with the file name. it works now :)

Comment: The compiler doesn't ever interact with `copyme` file; the compiler just compiled your code into an executable...

Answer (score 2):

change

```
   if ( (in = fopen(in_name, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open %s for reading.\n", in_name);
        return 1;
    }
```

to

```
   #include <errno.h>
   if ( (in = fopen(in_name, "r")) == NULL)
    {

        perror("Can't open file for reading.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

you will get a human readable message telling you why it cant read the file

Comment: I don't think this provides an answer to the question.

Comment: it very useful advice and too long to put in a comment

Comment: It is very useful, and a very good comment. But this just doesn't fit as an answer. I know it will be a little big for a comment. May be a link to an example would have been good.

Comment: @pm100 thank you! I didn't know about `#include <errno.h>

Comment: (+1)  On the contrary, this actually does answer his unclear question; he asks  for help and asks why can't the file be found; this will get him that answer

Comment: @Haris what would you even define his question to be?

Comment: @UpAndAdam, If the OPgot help from this post, then its good. I just pointed out that this provides a way in which the OP will get the answer, but itself isnt one. Anyways, if it was helpful then its good. :)

Comment: a. You can't define an answer to an undefined question.  Question is poorly defined
b. It's about more than just OP; its about will ANYONE benefit from this post.  The actual answer is the OP's typo, that's useless to everyone. This bit is extremely useful, and if followed the OP would have answered his own question.